# Convert comma string list of int to enum and back

Tags: c#, list, enums

I have the following enum type defined:

```
public enum Level
{

    [XmlEnum("1")] ReadLevel = 1,
    [XmlEnum("2")] WriteLevel = 2, 

}
```

I also have a list defined which has the type of this enum

```
public List<Level> MyList
```

I want to store the list as a comma seperated string with the numbers and read it back and use the enum levels in conditional statements.

The set method I have defined, but how do I markup the get method? Currently

```
 get
 {
    return string.Join(",", MyList);
 }
```

returns me the text of the enum (like ReadLevel, WriteLevel)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about why you want to do this? It would seem much better to serialize it as a list if you can

Comment: @AluanHaddad  You have an example of what you mean?

Comment: no I'm asking why you're doing this at all?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Well I'm learning serialization.

Comment: if you're serializing to XML you can represent the list as a set of child elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting your `enum` objects to `int`

```
get { return string.Join(",", MyList.Select(x => (int)x)); }
```

Comment: You don't need `ToList` - avoid superstitious code.

Comment: Thanks Aluan, I said in the comment that the toList may be not needed

Comment: Thanks. Works without the ToList